How to Properly Connect Crossing Railway Tracks without Overlaps?
I'm working on a 3D model of French railway switches in Blender, and I've run into a problem. My model includes the following components:
The Frog (green), which is already complete.
Standard rails (blue) that end where they meet the frog.
Wing rails (red) that overlap with the standard rails and need to transition smoothly into them without any excess parts.
In the attachments, you can see an image of my current Blender setup and a reference image of a real railway switch.
Current 3D Model:

Reference Image:

My goal is to make the blue and red rails "merge" seamlessly at the transition, so there are no overlapping parts and the wing rails (red) meet the standard rails (blue) smoothly. So far, I've tried the following:
Merging: I merged the rail parts.
Intersect (Knife): I used the "Self-Intersection" option with the tool.
Merging Vertices by Distance: I merged vertices by distance and then tried to manually delete the overlapping vertices at the ends of each rail section.
However, this doesn’t seem to work, as vertices aren’t being created where some edges intersect. This leaves overlapping rail sections and creates messy transitions.
How can I correctly cut these overlapping parts and connect the rails so they look like the reference image? Is there a more efficient method or a specific setting with the knife tool that I may have missed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
